# Wordpress Twentyseventeen theme: where to find what is controlling the header size

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site using the TwentySeventeen theme, which has been dormant for a year or more. When it was in use, the header graphic was somehow reduced in height. I have no information on how that was done. I now want to restore the header height to the default height for TwentySeventeen.

I have searched and looked at every question and answer I can find. After checking all the css and php where I can find reference to header dimensions, the static homepage is showing the full size, but posts and pages are still showing a reduced header size.

Finally, I downloaded a fresh copy of the TwentySeventeen theme and uploaded it to the site, overwriting all existing files. Still the posts and pages are showing a reduced header size.

There is no custom css in the dashboard settings. I have cleared my browser cache. I don't know where else to look. Can anybody tell me what is left to check?

**Added in response to comment below:**

I'm a bit out of my depth with the Inspector, and I don't know what you need to see from it. There are three different panes, all of which have more than one screenshot of content. Unfortunately I am not able to publish the URL at this point.

The first screenshot is the Inspector for static homepage -- which displays the full-size header graphic.

The second screenshot is the Inspector for posts and pages -- which displays a  shallow header graphic.

Both share the same style.css file.

[image: Inspector for static homepage -- full-size header graphic]

[image: Inspector for posts and pages -- shallow header graphic]

I note the line:
box-sizing: inherit;

-- but I'm not sure if this is pertinent?

Comment: Inspect your header with the browser's dev tools and post as much information as possible here; styles, screenshots of the inspector, possibly a link to your website.

Comment: Question edited accordingly

Comment: So where do the `608px` height for the homepage header come from? Not from the default `style.css` apparently, because I don't have that in my version of the twentyseventeen theme. Try to locate the CSS file, or maybe it's a inline style, which you can see in your HTML inspector.

Comment: Well, that's my question, Michael. What is causing the difference between the static home page with full depth at 608 and the post page with depth at 69? I have compared all the css files with the default TwentSeventeen files, and ended up just repacing all the theme files with a fresh version of the theme. I can't find what is causing this.